# should refactor android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment to android.app.DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I should refactor code in my custom dialog class below.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;

public class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public BaseActivity parentActivity;

    protected void showMessage(String title, String message) {
        MessageDialogFragment dialog = MessageDialogFragment.newInstance(title, message);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show(parentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), MessageDialogFragment.TAG);
    }

    //...

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (getChildFragmentManager().getFragments() != null) {
            for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want convert it:

```
android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

to:

```
android.app.DialogFragment;
android.app.Fragment;
```

And I can not do it correct rewrite this:

```
for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
```

Please, tell me how to do it right.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, first why you should refactor your code ? Then, I don't understand the last part, you can't achieve to refactor this part of your code : for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }

Comment: Hi Arrabidas92, I should refactor because our app support minSdkVersion 17,  and get it task to refactor code. And yes, i cant achieve to refactor this part of my code...

Comment: Well, I always hear that is better to keep support library compared to the original one. The problem is that there is no methods on the "normal" library able to provide the list of Fragments I think. With normal API, you have something like this : "for (Fragment fragment : getFragmentManager().getFragment(Bundle bundle, String TAG)) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

Comment: thanks but all the same, i need working solution without support library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find work solution but I'm not completely sure about it. I want to see your comments.

Add list fragments here:

```
private List<WeakReference<Fragment>> fragList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
        ArrayList<Fragment> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (WeakReference<Fragment> ref : fragList) {
            Fragment f = ref.get();
            if (f != null) {
                if (f.isVisible()) {
                    ret.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act) {
        super.onAttach(act);
        if (act instanceof BaseActivity) {
            parentActivity = (BaseActivity) act;
            fragList.add(new WeakReference(getActiveFragments()));
        }
    }
```

And here i refactor like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        for (WeakReference<Fragment> fragmentWeakReference : fragList) {
            fragmentWeakReference.get().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```